# Magento use different size chart for different products

Tags: magento, product

I'm having e-commerce store built by magento. In product we are having a size chart which shows the sizes for men and women in detail. To do this i included the below jscript code

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- function myPopup2() {window.open( "http://www.mydomain.com/sizechart/sizechart.html", "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 700, width = 864, resizable=1, scrollbars=yes" )}//--></script>
```

`<p class="sizechart" onClick="myPopup2()">CHECK YOUR SIZE</p>`

in `app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/templates/category/products/view.phtml`

We are planning to sell sunglasses also in our store. so we created a new category & uploaded products related to sunglasses. The only problem is, same men & women's wear size chart is showing here also. I want to display size charts according to category.
Lets say if we go to mens wear page it should show only mens related size charts, same will go for womenswear & sunglasses.

How to do this,
Please give me solution to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do something like :

```
<p class="sizechart" onClick="<?php if(product_in_cat1):{echo 'functionforsizechart1';} else:{echo 'functionforsizechart2';} endif;?>">CHECK YOUR SIZE</p>
```

This should be a temporary solution, as you type of products will increase and you add different size charts, this process may become cumbersome